# Javascript: Animation after "animationend" event handling

Tags: javascript, events, listener, css-animations

Commuity,

I have a problem with a specific piece of code I am writing currently. The problem is that i want to delegate the animations. (E.g. I have 3 objects, the first is animated, after that the second and after that the third)

The point is I am trying to make it modular so i can't hard code anything in there.

**On start we have following situation:**

**parentDiv** is supposed to contain the objects you want to "fadeIn"

**prevDiv** is the object which was "fadedIn" recently

**onclickDisabled** is a class to remove "click" events temporarily

**fadeInAnim** is the class to trigger needed animation

```
function prepareChildrenForFadeInAnimation(parentDiv, prevId){
    var object = 0;
    parentDiv.children().each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('onclickDisabled');
        addAnimationAfterAnimationEnd($(this)[object].id, prevId);
        prevId = $(this)[object].id;
    });

}

function addAnimationAfterAnimationEnd(currentSelection, prevSelection){
    document.getElementById(prevSelection).addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", triggerNextAnimation(currentSelection, prevSelection));
    document.getElementById(prevSelection).addEventListener("animationend", triggerNextAnimation(currentSelection, prevSelection));
}

function triggerNextAnimation(selection, prevSelection){
    selection = $('#'+selection);
    selection.addClass('fadeInAnim');
    prevSelection = $('#'+prevSelection);
    prevSelection.removeClass('onclickDisabled');
}
```

I have a feeling that in **addAnimationAfterAnimationEnd()** the function **triggerNextAnimation()** is fired, but I don't have a clue how to prevent this since I need to submit parameters (or do I?).

If one of you guys could help me out I would be overjoyed!

*PS: I am using "Chrome" and "Firefox" for testing.*

Comment: If I understand correctly the current code animates all children of `parentDiv` at the same time but you want the children to animate one after the other. Correct?

Comment: @Halcyon Yes indeed. I am having the problem that the second and third object are "fadedIn" when the eventHandler is bound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript at Question is calling the function `triggerNextAnimation(currentSelection, prevSelection)` immediately instead of referencing the function to be called when event is dispatche at the object.

You can use `Function.prototype.bind()` or `$.proxy()` to reference the function which should be called when the event is dispatched and with `this` set to a specific object and pass parameters.

Also, it is not necessary to use vendor prefix if you are already using jQuery. You can use `.on("animationend")`

```
document.getElementById(prevSelection).addEventListener("animationend", 
triggerNextAnimation.bind(null, currentSelection, prevSelection))
```

Comment: Oh nice, thanks for the fast feedback. The "triggerNextAnimation.bind()" solution helped me with that problem. Now it looks as smooth as desired :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the function, which was supposed to trigger after certain animation, was simply executed.

```
document.getElementById(prevSelection).addEventListener("animationend", 
triggerNextAnimation.bind(null, currentSelection, prevSelection));
```

The code above solves this problem. "Function.bind()" enables me to specificaly call the function after an event